# Ignoring the images at the time of crawl

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

How can I ignore the images during the crawl with the scrapy to speed up the crawl?

This will speed up the creep speed.
The download is less.

How can I make scrapy ignore certain tags and totally ignore html attributes?

Comment: @ArshCoder Unfortunately no, I saw this question before.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague.  Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for attention .When Scrapy checks a page, it downloads the entire resources. Like CSS and JavaScript files and images.
What to do so that the photos are not crawled by Scrapy?

Comment: like screamingfrog: https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/user-guide/configuration/#check-images

Comment: That isn't true though.  When scrapy sends an http request it only receives the http response.  Anything extra it does not receive.   In order to get the images you have to specifically request them

Comment: @Alexander Most Web Crawler are able to ignore images to improve the internet bandwidth and high speed in crawling.

Comment: Okay... scrapy doesn't download the images by default they have to be explicity requested  I think your referring to gui crawlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the test I did. I realized that Scrapy doesn't download any images and videos by default.